# how to write large number of data to an outputStream (Like 1million rows of string)

Tags: java, android, http, outputstream

I need to update my android application's clients with like 1million rows of data base each time they want, according to my test, with just 15k of rows :

```
 over PrintWriter : 1.5min
 over DataOutputStream : 2min
 over Header : 30sec
 over Writer : 30sec
```

but all of them just with 15k of rows are unacceptable, my server is a http server written with java, i have tried to write the data to file, but again for just 15k the file size will be 3mb, is there by any chance any workaround for this?

Edit -

I have tested this on a simulated wifi server and on a real device; the server is running within Eclipse. Would changing the server to Tomcat help?

Comment: First of all, you don't use an `OutputStream` to write character data, but a `Writer`

Comment: good to know, ill try with a writer too

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough information about your test. What were the conditions? What network were you using? Was this with a real device or an emulator? If you want to transfer 66x that much information - i.e. over 198MB, you should *expect* that to be pretty slow, especially over a mobile network connection. It may well cost your users a lot of money, too. You should think about ways of reducing the amount of data you need to transmit. We can't help you do that without more information.